# Infinitive Marker

Tags: parts-of-speech, infinitive, particles

In English, is the infinitive marker a part of speech? I noticed that Oxford was using it in the PoS lexical entry position for one sense of "to": https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/to

"Bob wants ***to*** eat pizza."

If not, is it a particle - and the particle is a part of speech?

Comment: Yes, it's a part of speech. In CGEL, it's analyzed as a subordinator, whose primary function is that of marker of subordination.

Comment: The infinitival 'marker' (function) belongs to the part of speech 'subordinator'.

Comment: @BillJ Doesn't a "subordinator" take a full clause as its argument, not a VP?

Comment: +1 But you really need to wait a few days before accepting an answer on here. Otherwise people who might otherwise spend time writing you an answer may not bother to. (That's the situation with me, for example, right now)

Comment: "To" is a special marker for the VPs of _to_-infinitival clauses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out, "parts of speech" are one of those formalisms that's taught in all the schools, but isn't always useful when you start looking closer.

Fundamentally, "part of speech" is a word's role in the syntax. "Walk" and "run" and "go" and "travel" all act pretty much the same, syntactically, so it makes sense to say "all of these things are Verbs, and this is how Verbs act". And then you find words like "eat" that act *almost* the same, but not quite, so you separate them into "Intransitive Verbs" and "Transitive Verbs", and write some rules about Intransitive Verbs and some about Transitive Verbs, and some about all Verbs in general.

But this stops being useful when words act, syntactically, like *nothing else in the language*.

The "infinitive *to*" appears in only one construction. It takes the bare form of a verb, and turns it into either a non-finite verb or a verbal noun, depending who you ask. And there's no other word in English that can do the same thing. It looks just like the "preposition *to*", but it doesn't act as a preposition: you can't say **he wants for go now*, or **he wants behind go now*.

So, historically, the solution was to call it a "particle"—where "particle" means "we don't know what category to put this in, but it needs a category". (In English at least: in a few languages, "particles" are a legitimate category of words that all act the same.) But as far as actually doing syntactic analysis, I'd just keep it in a class all of its own, which is what most POS-taggers will do: the Penn treebank, for example, gives it the special tag `TO` shared with no other word.

Comment: Historically the Infinitive particle "to" was a preposition for the inclined form. For example: drinkan - to drinkenne.

Comment: The infinitival marker "to" belongs to the category (part of speech) subordinator.

Comment: @user307254 the inclined form sounds so much like Saxon :) btw, German *zu* is like *to* for the subordinate clause, "Ich wünsche zu trinken". That **shouldn't be confused with the English infinitive marker *to*** and much less the preposition, but isn't that exactly what happened for English? Similar confusion gives *etwas zu trinken; zu trinken; Trinken*. The preposition can appear in verbs, *zuschauen*, thus reduplicating *um zuzuschauen*. German doesn't have any infinitive marker (the infinitive is homophone with 1. and 3. p. pl.). Why label infinitives at all, unless for dicts?

Comment: @user307254 Interesting, Latin also formed its infinitives out of an inflected form of the verbal noun (I think it was a locative for the active and a dative for the mediopassive).

Comment: @billj Not according to Pullum, or many others.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, the infinitive marker *to* has a part of speech (POS) label. What exactly it is depends on your POS tagset. In the [Penn Treebank tagset](https://www.clips.uantwerpen.be/pages/mbsp-tags) there is a special tag `TO` only for the infinitive marker (sometimes merged with the preposition depending on the corpus and the tagger used), in another tagset is may be just a `PART` (particle) togeter with other particles of different rôles.

Comment: It belongs to the category (POS) subordinator. Marker is its function, not its POS.

Comment: @BillJ Huh? That sound like very special terminlogy not shered among the people dealing ith part-of-speech tagsets.

Comment: Who's talking about 'tagsets'? The OP certainly isn't (look at his question). H&P discuss this in GGEL, where they demonstrate that 'subordinator' is preferable to ''defective verb' (the only other possibility).